# Why doesn't the tilde "~" come up the first time?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard

Yes, strange. (I've got this lengthy list of computer-related questions and I thought today would be the day to ask this one, while I was at it with a few others. Thanks in advance!)

The problem: When I go to press shift-tilde, nothing happens. Any key pressed after brings up the missing tilde and that key.

Keyboard stuck? or programming error?

edit: It seems this occurs in any application: browser, word processor, etc.

edit2: completely forgot the specs: XP, Logitech wireless keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What language is your keyboard set to?

At one time I had my keyboard set to `UK(International)` - as such pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> (for example) would do nothing, *but* following that with a press of a relevant letter (eg <kbd>E</kbd>) would produce the letter with the relevant diacritic - in this example probably `é`.

This would work <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> with a variety of keys that would represent a diacritic followed by a valid letter. If you're fussed see [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#United_Kingdom_extended) article on that keyboard setup.

A further [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) search shows that `n` sometimes has a tilde in Spanish, such as `ñ`.
You could try doing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> and then <kbd>N</kbd> and see what happens.

Comment: +1. I'm in Canada, and for some reason, every so often I get a keyboard switching to French (I work in an IT shop so I see a lot of machines), even though it's not supposed to. I usually end up using US settings to avoid this.

Comment: @Randolph - FYI: In Windows you can configure a key combination to switch between languages and/or keyboard layouts. I think it's inside Regional and Language Options somewhere.

Comment: This is the correct explanation. I realized after reading your answer that I was using my wife's Polish keyboard and settings. (Why didn't I think of that!? :-) So, even though the right ALT key followed by certain letters will produce the special Polish letters, I never caught on that pressing SHIFT + tilde + certain letters will also do the same special Polish letters. Weird, but it looks to be true. Am I making sense? Thanks! I appreciate it.  BTW: how did you get the emboss effect for the keys in your answer?

Comment: yup, well aware of the key combination, but it doesn't always work. I figure it's easier to just make the keyboard US English unless it's a French customer, which is hardly ever.

Answer (score 1):

Check your keyboard manual - does it allow for programming macros etc.? If so, it's probably the keyboard or the keyboard's software thinking you're about to send it a command.

One way to find out - plug in a non-wireless keyboard (don't bother removing the wireless one, Windows works fine with two plugged in, in my experience) and see if it happens with the other keyboard as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is your control key stuck?  What happens if you try to use a colon `:` or a carot `^`?

Comment: You mean caret? :P

Comment: I tried this and other key combinations. Sorry if I didn't write this in the OP. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to another computer via something like ssh?  Sometimes they intercept ~ as a terminal control character, if it at the beginning of the line.

Comment: No; but the keyboard is a wireless Logitech, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check by typing the same key combination by using the 'Onscreen Keyboard'.
2. Check that you've not assigned this key combination to some windows commands. E.g. changing the keyboard layout or changing languages etc.